# Grid inside node with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

This snippet...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mygrid}{\tikz{\draw[step=2.5mm] (0,0)  grid (1,1);}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, draw]
    {
        \mygrid
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

generates this picture:

[image: rectangle with a grid]

What I should do to make the grid occupy the whole square (starting at the left bottom angle and terminating at the top right angle)? Should I use `pic` instead of nesting two pictures?

Comment: `\node[inner sep=0pt,rectangle,draw]`?

Comment: You should never nest `tikzpicture`s. That is, if it works, it is by accident and not by design. Hence, if it breaks, you get to figure out how to glue all the itsy-bitsy little pieces back together again. You could, however, save the grid in a box and then `\usebox{}`. That is, as I understand it, safe. Then add the zero `inner sep` suggested by @Manuel.

Comment: But why would you want to do this? Why not just draw the grid? Why do you want it in a node?

Comment: Thank you Manuel, it works. Unfortunately this does not work in a bit more complex situation that is what I need. And that's also the reason why I didn't just draw the grid @cfr.

I tried to update the original question according your comment but.... I think it's better if I write a new question. Thanks!

Comment: So why can't you use a box as I suggest? That should be safe, which may be a disadvantage, I suppose, if you especially want to live dangerously.

Comment: I have understood that nesting tikzpicture is something to avoid. But I started to learn tikz few days ago and even if I tried, at the moment I have not yet been able to write some working code that use box or pic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mygrid}{\tikz{\draw[step=2.5mm] (0,0)  grid (1,1);}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, draw, inner sep=0]
    {
        \mygrid
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution originally proposed by @Manuel works correctly.

Comment: `tikzpicture`s should ***not*** be nested!

Comment: @cfr  Could you show how to make it better?

Comment: @cis Use a box.

Comment: I do not know what you mean. But no problem. It is not my question. It does not interest me that much either. If I need it, I'll find out for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `path picture`

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\Height{3} 
\def\Width{5} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle, draw,
text width=\Width cm, text height=\Height cm,
] [inner sep=0, path picture={
\draw[step=0.5, red] (path picture bounding box.south west) grid (path picture bounding box.north east);
}]{Possible text in the node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```